# RACObserve property with custom getter

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I would like to observe the following property…

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter = isConnected) BOOL connected;
```

with the following code…

```
RACSignal *connectedSignaler = RACObserve(communicationManager, connected);
```

It does not work because of the **custom getter**. If I remove the custom getter it works fine.

Can someone tell me why this does not work and what I can do to work around the problem?

*P.S. I have also tried RACObserve(communicationManager, isConnected);*

Comment: How is the property being set? `RACObserve` is just a wrapper for KVO, so you need to ensure that your updates are KVO-compliant.

Comment: Yes, as I said it works fine without the getter=. I have tried it out with KVO and the problem is there not in RACObserve.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I tracked the problem down. The isConnected getter was overridden by the class. I would have thought only overriding the setter would cause problems but I live and learn.